# Facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"ALBUM_ID/photos" not returning the entire album

Tags: iphone, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

Could you tell me why this request is only returning a partial number of the photos in the album? Because I have an album with 99 photos and only 25 are getting returned in the array it produces.

I call the request with this code:

```
-(IBAction)showAlbum:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //Go goes here to get an album and display it in the UIScrollView
    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"ALBUM_ID/photos" andDelegate:self];    
}
```

And I get the array of photos using this code:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    //Code for array of photos
    NSArray *photoAlbumArray=(NSArray*)[result valueForKey:@"data"];
    [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [photoAlbumArray count]]];
}
```

The label should read "99" but instead it reads "25". Additionally when I load the photos from the array only 25 photos appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most facebook graph api calls have a default limit of 25 items returned and support limit and offset parameters.  You could request `ALBUM_ID/photos?limit=100` instead.

Comment: Wow, you made that incredibly simple. Thanks @OffBySome - could you tell me what the offset does? Because while limit is pretty straightforward and intuitive the offset isn't. Also, say I initially do a limit of 50 instead of a 100. Is there way to do a second call that starts at 51 and gets the remainder?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out the offset thing. Could you confirm whether this is true? If I want to start at 50 and get the remaining (50) I should do the following: `ALBUM_ID/photos?offset=50&limit=50` - where the offset essentially means "jump ahead by this many" and the limit means "collect up to this amount"

Comment: Yes that is correct - offset is for paging and lets you skip the first X amount of records.

Comment: Cool. And just curious, in one of the Facebook tutorials/blogs,[link](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/), they mention that "when querying the [photos], use time-based paging instead of “offset” to ensure you are getting back as many results as possible with each call. For these Graph API connections, use the “since” and “until” parameters (e.g.
https://graph.facebook.com/chickfila/posts?until=1298508006) - However, since the graph api returns time parameters in the form of
2011-02-02T16:48:02+0000, as opposed to 1298508006, is there a
conversion method available?

Comment: Or should I just stick with offset ...? Thanks again @OffBySome

Answer (score -1):

I just figured how to query all the images in an album without knowing how many photos are there: just pass "0" (ALBUM_ID/photos?limit=0)

Comment: sorry dude. limit 0 returns nothing.

Comment: To get all images pass the value of count key present in the data of albums get from Facebook.